# Why is vector v parallel in this parametric equation?

Tags: vectors, parametric

I was reading through my textbook on parametric equations and I came across the following question:

(a) Find parametric equations and symmetric equations of the line that passes through
the points A(2,4,-3) and B(3,-1,1).

The solution is as follows:

Solution:
We are not explicitly given a vector parallel to the line, but observe that the vector
with representation, AB is parallel to the line, and v= (1,-5,4)

Thus, direction numbers are a=1, b=-5, and c=4. Taking the point (2,4,-3) as Po we see the that the parametric equations are x=2+t, y=4-5t, z=-3+4t.

My question is: Why is vector v parallel to the line? It seems all that was done was calculate A-B, the difference of the vectors, but that doesn't show why v would be parallel.

Comment: Name it $\vec{AB}$ instead of $\vec v.$

Comment: If the line passes through the points $A$ and $B$, it must be parallel to the vector that goes from $A$ to $B$. That vector is $B-A$.